# Add centered text over a full-page, darkened, blurred background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, opacity, css-filters

I want to create a homepage with a background image filling the full page height. Above that I need to add white text and other elements.

[This website](http://www.zomato.com/) is an example of what I want to achieve.

What I want:
[image: What I want]

How it looks:
[image]
With my CSS below, the text looks very faint.

```
#header
{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
#header-inside
{
    opacity: 1.0;
    /* background:none repeat scroll 0% 0% #efefef; */
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:2px 2px #000000;
}
#all {
    background:url("back.jpeg") no-repeat fixed center center;
    /*background-repeat:repeat-x;*/
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please add comment so that I can improve my question!

Comment: Add a good font and add some text shadow

Comment: I am not able to add image because I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: You can link to it, or I can add it for you. I have created a suggested edit so you can see a better format for a question. Please also post your HTML.

Comment: @Keavon as I said I am using drupal so HTML files are created by drupal depending upon the request so I don't have any HTML files..and How can I give you those images? I just need +3 to be able to upload the images! :(

Comment: @harrythomas Okay, that's much more clear now. Is your question related to how to center text over a background image, or is it asking how to darken the background image?

Comment: @ImagineStudios If you care, you can delete your comment at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a masking div. Have a look at this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/pefepuli/1/ (to edit the JSBin see [this link](http://jsbin.com/pefepuli/1/edit?html,css,output))

If you are wondering how the masking effect is achieved. It's all to do with the `background-color` property of the mask. We provide an `rgba` value, which stands for Red Green Blue Alpha. We can manipulate the alpha of the background color to change its opacity.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="pic">
  <div id="mask">
    <div id="txt">Your text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#mask {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,10,20,.6);
}

#pic {
  background-image: url('http://d2z9qv80fklwtv.cloudfront.net/images/homescreens/7-n.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  height: 782px;
}

#txt {
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried your demo but When I change my css from "background" to "background-image" it shows nothing in background! Why so? Thanks

Comment: @harrythomas Hard to say without knowing exactly how your entire CSS looks. Can you provide a jsfiddle or jsbin?